# ReactJS: Can not type into input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting to learn react and download and follow any tutorials in internet. I am trying to build friend list.
I have tree components,

friends_container:

```
import React from 'react';
import AddFriend from './add_friend.jsx'
import ShowList from './show_list.jsx'

class FriendsContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            friends: ['Jake Lingwall', 'Murphy Randall', 'Merrick Christensen']
        }
    }

    addFriend(friend) {
        this.setState({
            friends: this.state.friends.concat([friend])
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3> Add your friend to friendslist </h3>
                <AddFriend addNew={this.addFriend}/>
                <ShowList names={this.state.friends}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FriendsContainer;
```

add_friend:

```
import React from 'react';

class AddFriend extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {newFriend: ''};
    }

    updateNewFriend(e) {
        this.setState({
            newFriend: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleAddNew() {
        this.props.addNew(this.state.newFriend);
        this.setState({
            newFriend: ''
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.newFriend} onChange={this.updateNewFriend}/>
                <button onClick={this.handleAddNew}>Add Friend</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

AddFriend.propTypes = { addNew: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired };

export default AddFriend;
```

show_list:

```
import React from 'react';

class ShowList extends React.Component {

    render() {
        var listItems = this.props.names.map((f, i) => <li key={i}>{f}</li>);
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Friends</h3>
                <ul>
                    {listItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ShowList.defaultProps = { names: [] };


export default ShowList;
```

and app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import FriendsContainer from './components/friends_container.jsx';

window.React = React;

React.render(<FriendsContainer />, document.body);
```

as you can see on the code, I am using es6 and babel as transcompiler.
My problem, I can not type any letters into the input field to add new friend into friends list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your `updateNewFriend` method, `this` refers to the window object and not the current component instance. You need to bind the method before passing it as the `onChange` event handler. See [`Function::bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

You have two options:

```js
class AddFriend extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        // ...
        this.updateNewFriend = this.updateNewFriend.bind(this);
        this.handleAddNew = this.handleAddNew.bind(this);
    }

}
```

or

```js
class AddFriend extends React.Component {

   render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.newFriend} onChange={this.updateNewFriend.bind(this)}/>
                <button onClick={this.handleAddNew.bind(this)}>Add Friend</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that `Function::bind` returns a new function, so binding in `render` creates a function every time your component is rendered, though the performance impact is negligible.

Comment: Do I have to bind function every time, when I use this in the function?

Comment: Only for functions that you pass as props or as event handlers. See [the mdn doc on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Using strict mode won't affect that behavior. Using `React.createClass` instead of ES6 classes will autobind methods for you, so you don't have to bind them manually.

Comment: What is better, use `React.createClass` or ES6 classes?